# How to use SafeNet Authentication Client SDK to generate RSA key pair and sign?

Tags: rsa, pkcs#11

Is any one can provide RSA sample which use SafeNet Authentication Client SDK. The SDK only provide ECC sample. I changed something and C_GenerateKeyPair return failed. Sometimes return CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID            0x00000012. I use sample array

```
    /* Settings for the public key */
    CK_ATTRIBUTE tPubKey[] = 
    {
        {CKA_TOKEN,           &ck_False,        sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
        {CKA_CLASS,           &cko_PublicKey,   sizeof(CK_ULONG)},
        {CKA_KEY_TYPE,        &ckk_RSA,         sizeof(CK_ULONG)},
        {CKA_PRIVATE,         &ck_False,        sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
        {CKA_EC_PARAMS,       ec_params,        sizeof(ec_params)},
    };

/* Settings for the private key */
    CK_ATTRIBUTE tPrvKey[] = 
    {
        {CKA_TOKEN,           &ck_True,         sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
        {CKA_PRIVATE,         &ck_True,         sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
        {CKA_DERIVE,          &ck_True,             sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
        {CKA_SIGN,            &ck_True,            sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
    };
```

I change configure to RSA and I don't know what is ec_params.
Actually I don't detail of template for pub. key and template for priv. key for RSA.

```
CK_PKCS11_FUNCTION_INFO(C_GenerateKeyPair)
#ifdef CK_NEED_ARG_LIST
(
 CK_SESSION_HANDLE    hSession,               /* session handle */
 CK_MECHANISM_PTR     pMechanism,             /* key-gen mech. */
 CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR     pPublicKeyTemplate,          /* template for pub. key */
 CK_ULONG             ulPublicKeyAttributeCount,   /* # pub. attrs. */
 CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR     pPrivateKeyTemplate,         /* template for priv. key */
 CK_ULONG             ulPrivateKeyAttributeCount,  /* # priv. attrs. */
 CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phPublicKey,                 /* gets pub. key handle */
 CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phPrivateKey                 /* gets priv. key handle */
 );
#endif
```

Can any help me this.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned different storage classes for public and privatre parts:

```
    {CKA_TOKEN,           &ck_False,        sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
```

and

```
    {CKA_TOKEN,           &ck_True,         sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},
```

They must have same storage class `CKA_TOKEN` - both must point to `ck_True`.

Also try without `CKA_EC_PARAM`.